# Magento 1.9 A strange record found in customer table

Tags: magento-1.9, security

I have noticed that there is a weird customer created in my admin,

[image]

I'm sure this customer wans't created on the frontend because this is a B2B site, and I have removed the front-end registration for customers. Customers can only be created via Magento admin, or via CSV import.

I wonder how this weird record came into Magento database? How can I prevent this happenning again?

Comment: I' ve got also 3 strange customers from australia as follows: 1 - Name: Иван Валерьевич Бондаренко http://EB5gH4q2.com Кондратий Павлович Шульц http://EB5gH4q2.ru - Email: te8xsmbwu@bk.ru 2 - Name: Сегодня отличный день и что же нам еще http://01JzROvB.com Нужно в этом мире здесь и сейчас http://01JzROvB.ru - Email: viacheslavbogdanov1997@bk.ru 3 - Name: Является наилучшим методом для данного момента http://79lv0wbn.com А сейчас нам нужно взять от них компонеты http://79lv0wbn.ru - Email: lerasuvorkina@list.ru I've deleted those customers. Do i need to do something else?
Any ideas why this hap

Comment: Today i found similar user registered on my dev-environment (M2) - *Иван Валерьевич Бондаренко http:**fQvAMiFE.com Кондратий Павлович Шульц http:**fQvAMiFE.ru* https://gyazo.com/77fc9f62b44acbfc34421a9dc087de42

Comment: In my case the user was registered from the 95.81.204.203 and gone :\

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau but how was the record able to be inserted into the DB? this is the real concern.

Comment: By installing security patch SUPEE-8788 and SUPEE-9767 fixed the problem for me.